# Get Teradata BTEQ query result in a unix variable

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, teradata

I am writing a shell script, where I need a result of BTEQ query in Teradata into a unix variable.

I tried,

```
    testabcd=$(bteq << EOF 2>&1 >> $LOG_FILE
     .LOGON ${HOST}/${USER},${PASSWORD}
     DATABASE ${SRC_DB};
     .set width 2000;
      .set titledashes off;
     SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${SRC_DB}.${SOURCE_TABLE};
    .LOGOFF;
    .QUIT;
    .EXIT
     EOF)

      echo "The count is: " $testabcd
```

The query runs successfully but the variable is not assigned with the output. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't test right now, but there should be still a column header, try SELECT COUNT(*) (TITLE '') ...

Comment: No, I mean its okay it there's a column header, all I need is the same output in the variable.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this redirection:

```
2>&1 >> $LOG_FILE
```

This effectly means "send stderr and stdout to the file $LOG_FILE". Since stderr and stdout are being redirected, the command will not send any output to the shell, and so the command substitution will not capture anything. Example:

```
$ test=$(echo "Hello" 2>&1)
$ echo $test
Hello   // as expected
$ test2=$(echo "Hello" 2>&1 >> example.log)
$ echo $test2
        // is empty, as output has been redirected
$ cat example.log
Hello   // here is the redirected output
```

The output of the `bteq` command will be found inside `$LOG_FILE` - if you want to save it in a variable instead, then you need to remove the redirection:

```
testabcd=$(bteq << EOF 2>&1 
....
```

Comment: Thanks!! I tried by removing the >>$LOG_FILE path, but the problem was, BTEQ would send all status messages for the query as the output, and it would require a lot of processing to extract the only count I want, but I found EXPORT output to File option in BTEQ which solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

No need for an extra file:

```
testabcd=$(bteq << EOF 2>&1  |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>//"
 .LOGON ${HOST}/${USER},${PASSWORD}
 DATABASE ${SRC_DB};
 .set width 2000;
  .set titledashes off;
 SELECT '>'||COUNT(*) FROM ${SRC_DB}.${SOURCE_TABLE};
.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
.EXIT
 EOF)
```

`'>'||COUNT(*)`:  `>` to *mark* the output that we really want from the query.

`grep '^>'`: to filter the *marked* text. Avoid `bteq` artifacts.

`sed -e "s/^>//"`: to get *rid* of the *flag* `>`.

Comment: can you explain what grep and sed are doing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
testabcd(){
bteq << EOFBT |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>//"
.SET ERROROUT STDOUT
.SET ECHOREQ ON
.SET INDICDATA OFF
.SET QUIET OFF
.SET SIDETITLES OFF
.SET TIMEMSG QUERY
.SET TITLEDASHES OFF

.LOGON ${LOGIN_TD_DWC};

 SELECT '>'||'ANTON';

 .LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
EOFBT
}

var_test=$(testabcd)

echo $var_test
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldnot find any direct way to assign the query output to the variable, but instead had to write the output to the file and read it.

```
      ERR_COUNT_FILE="err_count.txt"
      cat null > $ERR_COUNT_FILE
      bteq << EOF >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
      .LOGON ${HOST}/${USER},${PASSWORD}
         DATABASE ${SRC_DB};
         .set titledashes off;
         .set heading '';
      .EXPORT FILE=${ERR_COUNT_FILE}

      SELECT COUNT(*) from ${SRC_DB}.${SOURCE_TABLE};

      .EXPORT RESET
      EOF
      sed -i '1d;s/[[:blank:]]//g' $ERR_COUNT_FILE /* Remove header line and all blank spaces from the file*/
      count_err=$(cat ${ERR_COUNT_FILE})
      echo $count_err
```

I could not find an easier way.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
count=$(echo "SELECT '>'||COUNT(*) FROM YOUR_DBNAME.YOUR_TABLENAME" | bteq .LOGON ${HOST}/${USER},${PASSWORD} 2>&1 |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>//");
```

Using this, we write a one line **bteq query** and result is stored in the variable `count`, so can be used.

No need for a extra file or anything.